# Why does the FreeBSD handbook recommend using a virtual console because of system messages?

Tags: freebsd, console

Quoting from the [FreeBSD Handbook](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/consoles.html), in section 4.2.1. “Virtual Consoles”:

> While the system console can be used to interact with the system, a user working from the command line at the keyboard of a FreeBSD system will typically instead log into a virtual console. This is because system messages are configured by default to display on the system console. These messages will appear over the command or file that the user is working on, making it difficult to concentrate on the work at hand.

What does it mean: log into a VC as system messages will display on the system console and will appear over the command making it difficult?

Comment: I assume that VC is virtual console.

Comment: Because the system writes errors to the main console, so it recommends that you don't use it.

Comment: It's clearer reading the text than your butchered every-other-word quote. What part don't you understand?

Comment: The part about system console, what is that? and why would the messages appear over the command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bit you quote is saying that the output of a system message can appear on a "system console". I'm not a BSD person, but linux can have this same issue. A "system console" would be a non-graphical console (i.e. TTY1), like where the kernel boot messages are displayed.

When a message is sent to the console to be displayed, it gets dumped out wherever the cursor currently is. This can be a major annoyance. Consider the following example:
Lets say you're using the **vi** editor, and currently the cursor is in the middle of the screen, and you're typing away. If a system message is sent to the console, it will be printed out exactly where your cursor is at. So the output of the message will obscure part of the file you're currently editing, making it difficult to read.

---

Generally these types of messages are only sent to the console if they're really important (syslog level EMERG or ALERT for example). This is done so that the message is seen right away. But sometimes what someone else deems as important isn't what you consider important, and so these messages can be a nuisance.

Answer (score 1):

The system console is where the FreeBSD kernel outputs its messages; ttyv0.

The line of text you quote is saying that if you use the system console for running commands then your input and the output of any commands you run will be interspersed with system messages making it harder to both make sense of the system messages and to make sense of any output your command types. So what the paragraph is recommending is that you switch to a Virtual Console (`Alt+F2`, `Alt+F3`) and log in there when you want to run some commands.

Think of it like trying to use the same keyboard and monitor at the exact same time as someone else; better to just go and use one that nobody else is using.